# jQuery MouseOver dropdown pushes div beside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover

I have made a drop down menu using jQuery. On mouse enter it opens and on mouse leave it closes.

**The Problem**

The menu seems to 'push' other elements beside.

jsFiddle working exapmle: http://jsfiddle.net/aXPVq/

**HTML**

```
<div id="floatingmenu">
    <h1>FLOATING MENU</h1>
    <div style="display: none;">
        FLOATING MENU TEST<br />
        FLOATING MENU TEST<br />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="menu">
    TEST<br />
    TEST<br />
    TEST<br />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function()
{
    $('#floatingmenu h1').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).next().slideDown(100);
    })
    $('#floatingmenu h1').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).next().slideUp(100);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#floatingmenu
{
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
#menu
{
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

**Question:** How can I stop the menu from pushing other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those float a messing with each other.

An easy solution is to put your floating menu in `position:relative` and add those CSS :

```
#floatingmenu div{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aXPVq/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use absolute positioning on the floating menu as it is not on the absolute right of the screen, but rather at the right of the container, which has a fixed width.

Comment: I don't follow you :/ Can you show me an img of what you want?

Comment: Here: http://dev-ch.com/files/cfd604e9-f665-7582-216c-3afb3b836eaa/dropdownmenu.jpg - As you see, the menu below that is pushed away

Comment: You cant realy achieve what you want without pos absolute since your elements overlap. But here, examine this : http://jsfiddle.net/aXPVq/13/ . Is that what you want?

Comment: Now that's what I want what I really really want :D

Answer (score 1):

You can give fix height to #floatingmenu div.

Comment: This is only a good solution when there's no background color involved.

Comment: what background color has to do with height?

Comment: See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/aXPVq/9/ - It should be all yellow, but only a heigth of 50px is yellow.

Comment: that is a different problem and can be solved by enclosing the drop down in another div http://jsfiddle.net/aXPVq/12/